# Use html hidden variable in canvasjs dataPoints

Tags: php, jquery, json, canvasjs

My dataPoints string saved in databse.
I pass that in hidden variable in php.
And using .val() i get in jquery.
Now i have to pass that in dataPoints of canvas js.

See my below php code.

```
<input type="hidden" id="graph_data" name="graph_data" value="<?php echo $graph_data ?>" >
```

$graph_data contain below sting.

{x: 30, y:[.00, 3.20], label: "Driving"},{x: 10, y:[3.20, 5.17], label: "Off-Duty"}

please see my jquery code.

```
var graph_data = $('#graph_data').val();

data: [
    {
        type: "rangeBar",
        dataPoints: [graph_data]
}]
```

but its not working.

Comment: What do you get when you do `console.log($('#graph_data').val())` ?

Comment: So the output you are generating would actually be `value="{x: 30, y:[.00, 3.20], label: "Driving"},{x: 10, y:[3.20, 5.17], label: "Off-Duty"}"` – should be obvious what’s wrong with that.

Comment: {x: 30, y:[.00, 3.20], label: "Driving"},{x: 10, y:[3.20, 5.17], label: "Off-Duty"}

Comment: Probably i am not sure but its wrong because from php i pass as string and in datapoints i used it as array? or something i don't know..

Comment: It’s because you are creating invalid HTML. You used `"` as the starting delimiter for your `value` attribute’s value, so naturally the next `"` _ends_ it – and after that comes gibberish.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that `graph_data` is a string.

Try: `var graph_data = JSON.parse($('#graph_data').val());`

Comment: What is your problem then?

Comment: If i copy and paste exact same string of php to datapoits then its working but if get in jquery and try to use that then its not working.

Answer (score 0):

I'm wondering if the problem isn't actually at the `data` since that is not encapsulated in an object.

```
var data = [
    {
        type: "rangeBar",
        dataPoints: [graph_data]
}];
```

Is this your error?

Comment: No i tried both way with array and without array but its not working.

Answer (score 0):

Ah! Try this: `<input type="hidden" id="graph_data" name="graph_data" value="<?php echo str_replace('"', '\\"', $graph_data) ?>" >`

I think what is happening is that the value='s quotation mark (") is being ended with the "Driving"'s quotation mark.

Answer (score 0):

You are definitely moving data the hard way.

PHP has a handy `json_encode()` function that will encode nearly any data for Javascript.  So instead of trying to hide complex data in a form, why not just make that data part of your javascript.

Like so:

```
<script>
var graph_data = <?php json_encode($graph_data); ?>;
var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer",
{
    data: [{
        type: "rangeBar",
        dataPoints: graph_data
    }]
};
<script>
```

As far as inserting complex data from PHP to Javascript goes, this should take care of your problem.  You can view the source in your browser to see how the data-to-json conversion came out and make sure you don't have any syntax errors.

Mind you, I'm not sure you have your usage of CanvasJS sorted out. From your original post it looked like you were having trouble with it, too.  But, one problem at a time.

Comment: i have to write this in jquery or php?

Comment: The json_encode part is PHP.  You can use that command to insert any data you like as if you had typed it into your page using javascript.